# Get Pay Pal Express Checkout details using authorize.net API

Tags: c#, vb.net, paypal, authorize.net

I'm using `authorize.net` API for checkout process in my web app. So, first step was passed, user has payed and I've got `token` and `PayerID`. But now I want to get user details. I've found such code in vb.net:

```
 postData.Append("USER=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PaypalUser"))
            postData.Append("&PWD=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PaypalPWD"))
            postData.Append("&SIGNATURE=" + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Signature"))
            postData.Append("&VERSION=95")
            Dim strParams As Dictionary(Of String, String)
            strParams = GetResponse(postData.ToString() + "&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails&TOKEN=" + Session("Paypal_Token"), "GetExpressCheckoutDetails", GetSessionID) 
Dim a = strParams("FIRSTNAME") 
...
```

But I want to use authorize.net API. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The API Methods supported by Authorize.Net for PayPal are listed in the API Reference: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#paypal-express-checkout